# The following build commands failed

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium

I hope someone can help me. I'm really crazy, I've tried everything.

A few days ago installed Titanium Studio on my Mac, then install Xcode. I created a "single window Application Project". Without touching anything special puslo RUN> iOS Simulator> iPhone Retina (3.5 inch).

The program begins to build until the prompt type:

```
[INFO]: Invoking xcodebuild 
[ERROR]: ** BUILD FAILED ** 
[ERROR]: The following build commands failed: 
[ERROR]: Ld build / Debug-iphonesimulator / helloworld.app / helloworld Normal i386 
[ERROR] (1 failure)
```

I updated all Xcode and everything related to Titanium.

Is there any solution?

I have read a lot a lot many forums, but I have not found any solution that works. I have cleaned the build folder, and even fails.

Can you think of anything?

Comment: Which sdk you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the command line tools for Xcode. Xcode -> Preferences, Downloads.

Also try checking if you have a folder that has the same name as the app itself?

Comment: Thansk... but... I installed Xcode command line tools for, then I deleted everything and I created a new project. 

But still get the error. Can you think of anything?

Comment: Nor is there a folder with the same name, basically because I've deleted everything. Jo!, Which took 2 days mulling over the problem. What a shame! ... Augh!, jeje

Comment: Hmmm, got me. Make sure everything everything is installed in appcelerator correctly, there may be some disparity between what Xcode installs and what appcelerator needs. It may also be something to do with your simulator settings in appcelerator, make sure you are targeting a version of iOS you have installed. I hope you find a solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a caching issue causing the build to fail.

1. Delete all `DerivedData` from your `Library`  root folder

   ```
   rm -rf /Users/<Your Username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
   ```

   Obviously, replace `<Your Username>` with whatever your username is *(if you're not sure, just run the `$ whoami` command)*
2. We need to clean cache

   - If you're using `npm`

   ```
   watchman watch-del-all; npm start -- --reset-cache;
   ```

   - If you're using `yarn`

   ```
   watchman watch-del-all; yarn start --reset-cache;
   ```
3. Re-install pods

   ```
   cd ios; pod install; cd ..;
   ```

This worked for me at the very least.